# Make mouse movements follow windmouse algorithm

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

Not sure if I'm asking the right question, but is it possible to make python move my mouse with things like pyautogui/selenium actions/or preferably all mouse movements following this algorithm? I want to make my mouse movements as real as possible for a bot I'd like to make. How would I go about doing this if possible? I found the algorithm here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210621155859/https://ben.land/post/2021/04/25/windmouse-human-mouse-movement/

```
import numpy as np
sqrt3 = np.sqrt(3)
sqrt5 = np.sqrt(5)

def wind_mouse(start_x, start_y, dest_x, dest_y, G_0=9, W_0=3, M_0=15, D_0=12, move_mouse=lambda x,y: None):
    '''
    WindMouse algorithm. Calls the move_mouse kwarg with each new step.
    Released under the terms of the GPLv3 license.
    G_0 - magnitude of the gravitational fornce
    W_0 - magnitude of the wind force fluctuations
    M_0 - maximum step size (velocity clip threshold)
    D_0 - distance where wind behavior changes from random to damped
    '''
    current_x,current_y = start_x,start_y
    v_x = v_y = W_x = W_y = 0
    while (dist:=np.hypot(dest_x-start_x,dest_y-start_y)) >= 1:
        W_mag = min(W_0, dist)
        if dist >= D_0:
            W_x = W_x/sqrt3 + (2*np.random.random()-1)*W_mag/sqrt5
            W_y = W_y/sqrt3 + (2*np.random.random()-1)*W_mag/sqrt5
        else:
            W_x /= sqrt3
            W_y /= sqrt3
            if M_0 < 3:
                M_0 = np.random.random()*3 + 3
            else:
                M_0 /= sqrt5
        v_x += W_x + G_0*(dest_x-start_x)/dist
        v_y += W_y + G_0*(dest_y-start_y)/dist
        v_mag = np.hypot(v_x, v_y)
        if v_mag > M_0:
            v_clip = M_0/2 + np.random.random()*M_0/2
            v_x = (v_x/v_mag) * v_clip
            v_y = (v_y/v_mag) * v_clip
        start_x += v_x
        start_y += v_y
        move_x = int(np.round(start_x))
        move_y = int(np.round(start_y))
        if current_x != move_x or current_y != move_y:
            #This should wait for the mouse polling interval
            move_mouse(current_x:=move_x,current_y:=move_y)
    return current_x,current_y
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you found is going to make human like mouse movement, instead of moving the mouse physically on your screen it will just help you plot the movements on the screen.

To help you see the plot, you can see in the same blog the writer/programmer has used Python matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[13,13])
plt.axis('off')
for y in np.linspace(-200,200,25):
    points = []
    wind_mouse(0,y,500,y,move_mouse=lambda x,y: points.append([x,y]))
    points = np.asarray(points)
    plt.plot(*points.T)
plt.xlim(-50,550)
plt.ylim(-250,250)
```

This block of code is just missing a plt.show() that will show the plot on your screen. Simply add,

```
plt.show()
```

at the end and you are good to go.

Now for the second part how can get physical Human like mouse movement. For that you can use a Python package pyHM. To install simply run this command in your shell

```
pip install pyHM
```

Then write this script, to move your mouse physically on the screen.

```
from pyHM import mouse
destination_x = 1000
destination_y = 500
mouse.move(destination_x, destination_y)
```

You might get an error for scipy.random.randit, let me know if you get this error I will help you out with that as well.